# Implicit differentiation of $x^4 +\sin y = x^3y^2$

Tags: calculus

I need help finding the implicit differentiation of $x^4 +\sin y = x^3y^2$
I especially need help finding $\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm dx}$for both sides. I'm having trouble with the product rule on the right side with $\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dx}$ of $x^3 y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it helps if you think of $y$ as a function of $x$, and in fact write $y=f(x)$. Then the product rule says
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^3y^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^3 f(x)^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)\cdot f(x)^2 + x^3\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(f(x)^2)$$
In order to continue, you need to calculate $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)^2)$ using the chain rule, and the result is $2\cdot f(x)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(f(x))$. Hence,
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^3y^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)\cdot f(x)^2 + x^3\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(f(x)^2)=3x^2f(x)^2+x^3\cdot 2\cdot f(x)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(f(x)).$$
Going back to the notation $y=f(x)$, and $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))$, we obtain
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^3y^2)=3x^2y^2+2x^3y\frac{dy}{dx}.$$

Comment: This one speaks precisely. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

$4x^3+(\cos y).y'=3x^2y^2+x^3.2y.y'$

Comment: Where all the y primes are, would I replace with dy/dx?

Comment: yes, I used $y'$ instead of $dy/dx$

Answer (score 0):

$4x^3+(\cos y)\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2y^2+2x^3y\frac{dy}{dx}$

Then solving for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ we have $2x^3y\frac{dy}{dx}-(\cos y)\frac{dy}{dx}=4x^3-3x^2y^2$ which is equivalent to:

$\frac{dy}{dx}(2x^3y-\cos y)=4x^3-3x^2y^2$.  Finally we have
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{4x^3-3x^2y^2}{2x^3-\cos y}$$